# pairs of numbers that have a difference of K

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

This was my online interview question, and I already submitted the answer. However, the compilation was terminated due to time so I just submitted. Could I get feedback from you? Thanks in advance.

Problem:

> Given N numbers , [N<=10^5] we need to count the total pairs of numbers that have a difference of K

Input Format:

- 1st line contains N & K (integers).
- 2nd line contains N numbers of the set. All the N numbers are assured to be distinct.

Output Format:

- One integer saying the no of pairs of numbers that have a diff K.

Sample Input #00:

```
5 2
1 5 3 4 2
```

Sample Output #00:

```
3
```

My code:

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*;

public class DiffNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line1 = in.readLine();
        String line2 = in.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(line1.split(" ")[0]);
        int diff = Integer.parseInt(line1.split(" ")[1]);

        Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for(in i=0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(line2.split(" ")[i]);
            table.put(Integer.parseInt(line2.split(" ")[i]));
        }

        int count = 0;

        for(in i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(table.containsKey(arr[i]+diff) {
                    count++;
            }
        }
        system.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: better located on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: your sample input doesn't match your description of the input format

Comment: @Ben this is not O(n^2) this is O(n).

Comment: I don't see anything to improve, one thing which I'm not sure is when you call `line2.split(" ")[i]`, will it split `line2` only `once` or `n times`? In the code it looks like n times but compilers are quite smart these days.

Comment: @smttsp Oh, thanks! I couldn't see that. Then do you know how to fix that problem?

Comment: There is not much difference but instead of calling `line2.split(" ")` N times, create String array once and use it. `String[] a = line2.split(" ")`. This is slightly more efficient. Other than that I see nothing to improve, but `MASTER`s might find better ways to improve

Comment: Was it specified that time or space complexity of your algorithm was a key factor of evaluation? You should not assume that interviewers always want you to demonstrate optimization abilities...

Answer (score 0):

Using HashMap/Table needs extra space. If you want to avoid it you can do it this way

1) Sort the array

2) initialize outputCount as 0

3) Let there be two pointers. "first" start with 0 and "Other" pointer start with 1.

4)

```
while(arr[other]-arr[first] <requiredDifference)
    other ++;
if(arr[other]-arr[first] == requiredDifference)
    outputCount++;
else  // no match for arr[first]
    first++;
```

5)

```
return outputCount;
```

explanation :- 
When difference is more than requiredDifference you stop moving ahead "other" poiner. So there is no match for arr[first]. So move ahead first counter. Now do the same logic for new arr[first]. This time you will continue checking from current position of "other" as array is sorted; lower number will not have required match.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the time complexity of this seems over O(n). Do you have any recommendation/solution for reducing time complexity to O(n)?

Comment: The time complexity of this proposition is bound to the time complexity of sorting the array of integers. Steps 2, 3 and 5 are constant. Step 4, which is incorrectly defined/indented, is a loop that will execute exactly N iterations of contant time, so O(n). The most efficient comparison-based sorts are O(n*log(n)), but a radix sort (assuming for example a "16 bits" radix, so integers are sorted in 2 pass), you get the whole thing sorted in O(2*n), so the whole thing can be completed in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line1 = in.readLine();
    String line2 = in.readLine();
    int diff = Integer.parseInt(line1.split(" ")[1]);

    Map<Integer, Object> nMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    Map<Integer, Boolean> uMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    Map<Integer, Boolean> lMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    String[] numbers = line2.split(" ");

    //init maps
    for(String number : numbers){
        Integer intValue = Integer.valueOf(number);
        nMap.put(intValue, new Object());  //original set, N
        uMap.put(intValue + diff, false);  //upper-bound map
        lMap.put(intValue - diff, false);  //lower-bound map
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(Integer nKey : nMap.keySet()){
        //Do if the lower-bound of n exists in N and if n hasn't used as an upper-bound?
        if(nMap.get(nKey - diff) != null && !uMap.get(nKey)){
            count++;
            //Mark the lower-bound as used.
            lMap.put(nKey - diff, true);
        }

        //Do if the upper-bound of n exists in N and if n hasn't used as an lower-bound?
        if(nMap.get(nKey + diff) != null && !lMap.get(nKey)){
            count++;
            //Mark the upper-bound as used.
            uMap.put(nKey + diff, true);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: You should explain a bit what your code does exactly.

Comment: @SebastianZartner, my bad.  I added comments.

Answer (score -3):

There's not much reason to store the integers in both an array and a hashtable. We can modify your code to do the all of the work in a single for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int j = Integer.parseInt(line2.split(" ")[i]) //probably not how I would go about this
    table.put(j);
    if(table.containsKey(j+diff)) {
        count++;
    }
    if(table.containsKey(j-diff)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. You insert `1` into table checked if `3` is in table which is not. Then inserted `5` checked `7` and so on. Your result will be 2 in this example